# Bash script to recursively copy files and folders when subdir is not present

Tags: bash, directory, copy

I have lots of projects archived under a directory tree, some of which have a .git folder in them.

What I'd like to do is recursively copy those files and directories to a new destination, keeping the current structure - EXCEPT for those directories containing a .git folder, in which case the script should run a command (let's say "echo", I'll change it later) followed by the folder name, without creating or copying it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:** I'll try to explain myself better: I need to copy every single file and directory, except for those containing .git, which should be skipped and their path should be passed to another command. In this example, path a/b/c/d and its subfolders should be skipped entirely and a/b/c/d should be displayed using echo (just for brevity, I'll replace it with a different command later):

```
a
a/b
a/b/c
a/b/c/d/.git
a/b/c/d/e
a/b/c/d/f/g
a/b/c/e
a/b/d
a/c
b
b/c
...
```

Comment: Is it an option to copy everything and remove the .git folders with find when you are finished?

Comment: Have a look, maybe, at `rsync` and its `exclude` option.

Comment: When you have a directory tree with `a/.git`, a/b/some.txt` and `a/c/.git`, do you want to skip the a/b folder?

Comment: @WalterA yes it's ok, as long as the command (echo) is run for each one of the folders containing a .git (basically I need to re-create them later using a different git command). And yes, as long as there's a .git in it, everything can be skipped.

Comment: I deleted my answer starting with `ls -d */`. @gniourf_gniourf commented correctly: , don't parse the output of ls, especially ls -d */ is horrible! I tested with dirs with spaces but it goes crazy when a dir contains a newline.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the following `find` one-liner will do the job:

```
find . -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -exec sh -c "test -e '{}/.git' && echo not copy '{}' || cp -r -- '{}' /tmp/copy-here " \;
```

Comment: `{}` is not meant to be used that way! you're allowing arbitrary code execution. Instead, use `-exec sh -c 'test -e "$0/.git" && echo "not copy $0" || cp -r "$0" /tmp/copy-here' {} \;`. Also, the modifiers `-mindepth 1` and `-maxdepth 1` are better put in front of the predicates; and they are not available in all versions of `find`. In fact, you could replace the `find` statement by a shell loop: `for f in */; do if [ -d "${f}.git" ]; then echo "not copy $f"; else cp -r -- "$f" /tmp/copy-here; fi; done`.

Comment: 1. Can you show an example when `{}` is insecure? 2. Why is it better to put `mindepth` and `maxdepth` at the beginning? 3. Yes, I know that [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/find.html) does not specify these options but OP didn't say what version of `find` he uses and `GNU find` is very possible 4. Yes, I know it could be done with a loop, I just chose `find` because I prefer it.

Comment: Oh, I forgot - putting a double minus after `cp -r` is a very good idea, I modified my answer

Comment: 1. There you go: if you have a directory named `'; ls #` then the command `ls` is going to be executed (and you're glad I only forged a friendly file name… replace `ls` by any evil command and cry).

Comment: 2. `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth`, as well as `-depth` modify the way `find` parses the directory tree; they are not _predicates_ like `-type` or `-exec` (even though they are treated as primary that evaluate to true). That's why I'm saying they should come first. Actually, my version of `find` complains if they don't come before the other predicates.

Comment: 3. That's an assumption you should specify in your post.

Comment: 4. You could also include the shell loop version, so as to have a more comprehensive answer `:)`.

Comment: Do you mean a directory created like this: `touch "'; ls #"`?

Comment: With `find`, the double hyphens in the `cp` command are not mandatory, since, very likely, the directory names will start with `./` and not a hyphen.

Comment: rather `mkdir "'; ls #"`.

Comment: Also, regarding #1: POSIX clearly states that _If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change._